# How to assign values for update_attributes in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a noob question about assigning values using update_attributes.

In the exam controller, a new exam record is saved and then an patient record is retrieved which matches some of the new exam fields. This part works fine.

```
@exam.save

@patient = Patient.joins(:charts).where(:dob => @exam.patient_dob).where(:charts => { :provider_id => @exam.provider_id, :patient_mrn => @exam.patient_mrn })
```

Then i try to update the new @exam record with a value from the @patient record using the following which crashes and burns......

```
@exam.update_attributes(:patient_id, @patient.id)
```

How have i gone so far astray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating a single value there, not multiple values, so `update_attribute` would be more appropriate. `update_attributes` takes a hash of values to update.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute and http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes

Comment: something to notice here **update_attribute** do not pass on validation rules but update_attributes do

Comment: Yes I chose update_attributes for the validation rules. But anyway i think my hash is not formatted correctly for either one.
i get undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x5f00808>
   -any suggestions??

Comment: Absolutely - `where` will always return you a relation, ie. a list of objects. If you just want the first one, call `.first` on it.